# how to create node in a node in a xml file from java dynamically

Tags: java, xml, dynamic, xml-parsing, testng

This is my xml file which i want to create dynamically from java code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="4" name="cool" verbose="5" parallel="tests">

 <test name="test_case6" parallel="tests">
    <parameter name="testsuite" value="Fleet"/>
    <parameter name="className" value="Fleet"/>
    <parameter name="methodName" value="TC_02"/>
    <parameter name="runtype" value="mobile"/>
    <parameter name="browser" value="NA"/>
    <parameter name="width_height" value="NA"/>
    <parameter name="deviceName" value="LGG3"/>
    <parameter name="deviceVersion" value="20"/>
    <parameter name="reportFolderName" value="Report6"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.igate.tests.GalenParallelMain">
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Here the name attribute value is hardcoded but the value attribute value will come dynamically.
I tried searching this , but all examples are very simple.

Comment: What have you tried? There's a very good demo going through it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_create_document.htm) that tells you what you need to do. You just need to modify it yuourself, have a go

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to create it via TestNG API, don't you?

```
    XmlClass xmlClass = new XmlClass();
    xmlClass.setName("com.igate.tests.GalenParallelMain");
    //        xmlClass.setClass(GalenParallelMain.class);

    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("runtype", "mobile");
    parameters.put("browser", "na");
    // ...

    XmlSuite xmlSuite = new XmlSuite();
    xmlSuite.setName("cool");
    xmlSuite.setThreadCount(4);
    xmlSuite.setVerbose(5);
    xmlSuite.setParallel("tests");

    XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(xmlSuite);
    xmlTest.setName("test_case6");
    xmlTest.setParallel("tests");
    xmlTest.setParameters(parameters);
    xmlTest.setClasses(Arrays.asList(xmlClass));

    // the XML you requested
    System.out.println(xmlSuite.toXml());

    TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
    testNG.setXmlSuites(Arrays.asList(xmlSuite));
    testNG.run();
```